# Columns wrapping in Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue with Bootstrap 4 grid layout. I'm trying to show a number of images (6 in a row) that will display all six in the row on larger screens, 3 on medium screens and 2 on smaller screens, and 1 on extra small. It seems that no matter what I try, my images keep wrapping to the next line. So at some point I'll have five or four images on the top line and 1 or two images on the bottom line. Is there a way I can prevent the images from wrapping and only show either 1, 2, 3, or 6 images in each row at a time?

What am I missing?  Any help is appreciated.

Here's a link to [a pen](https://codepen.io/hintonbradley/pen/dyyybpB)

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 img-container">
                <img class="image" src="010.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 img-container">
                <img class="image" src="010.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 img-container">
                <img class="image" src="010.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 img-container">
                <img class="image" src="010.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 img-container">
                <img class="image" src="010.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 img-container">
                <img class="image" src="010.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.img-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

  .img-container img {
    display: block;
    transition: transform .6s;
    max-width:auto;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .img-container:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.3);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }

  .image {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .row  {
      justify-content: space-around;
  }
```

Comment: I don't know about all your custom stylesheet. But regarding twitter-bootstrap grid, you are missing `col-lg-2` to show 6 images in a row on larger screens. Adding it to your `divs` should solve the problem.

Comment: I would move your `.img-container` to inside your `.col-*` divs. I wouldn't recommend messing with the `.col-*` divs display, width, height, padding, etc. or you risk messing up the grid system. Use the grid as scaffolding and place content inside the columns - don't alter the columns properties which is what you are doing by placing that `.img-container` class on them. So like this: `.container-fluid > .row > .col-* > .im-container > img`

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70dn5yfx/) as an example. Columns need to have dynamic width (thats what makes it responsive) and you are setting all columns to a static 200px

Comment: Thank you zgood. That fixed the problem. I thought it would be something simple like that.